# Spring RMI: How to expose without App server or servlet container?

Tags: spring, spring-remoting

I have a bunch of services that I've exposed over RMI with Spring. Currently, my app is configured as a web app and I deploy my app to JBoss to make my RMI services available. Is there a way that I can run my RMI exposed services without having to make my app a web app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is, just instantiate your Spring application context in a 'normal' (read: non-webapp) application and define your service and the exporter for it:

```
<bean id="myService" class="my.example.MyServiceImpl">
    <!-- properties -->
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
    <!-- does not necessarily have to be the same name as the bean to be exported -->
    <property name="serviceName" value="myRMIService"/>
    <property name="service" ref="myService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="my.example.MyService"/>
    <!-- defaults to 1099 -->
    <property name="registryPort" value="1199"/>
</bean
```

This way your service will be available at `rmi://HOST:1199/myRMIService`.

Read the full docs on RMI [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/remoting.html#remoting-rmi). If you aren't familiar with how to instantiate a Spring context, read [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-instantiation).